# Is there a minimum principle which governs neuronal activity in brain function?

Tags: variational-principle, biophysics, biology, network

[Reinforcement learning](http://incompleteideas.net/papers/barto-sutton-97.pdf) is a well established field which attempts to explain the behavior and decision-making of [toddlers](https://towardsdatascience.com/reinforcement-learning-brain-and-psychology-part-1-introduction-b5f79a0475ab), among other agents. The core principle of this theory is based on [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) which is an alternate formulation of the [minimum principle](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC527981/). Is it then a fair guess, to say that there might be a minimum principle for neuronal activity governing the functioning of the human brain?

Comment: "Karl Friston has proposed an ambitious framework which suggests that the function of the brain is to minimise a quantity known as free energy" according to this link; https://towardsdatascience.com/empowerment-as-intrinsic-motivation-b84af36d5616

Comment: https://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~karl/The%20free-energy%20principle%20A%20unified%20brain%20theory.pdf

Comment: Both links are very interesting. Thanks @Wolphramjonny!

Comment: "*Is there a minimum principle which governs neuronal activity in brain function?*" - No, but there is a maximum principle based on the power consumption. A human brain works at a constant power that is enough only for a small fraction of a percent of all neurons firing at any moment.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with physics?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: I apologize in advance in case this question is considered to be off-topic. Thanks to the contributors for pointing me to these interesting papers on the [*bio-physics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biophysics) of brain function. It seems to me that bio-physics is a multi-disciplinary science which requires knowledge of biology and mathematical physics with the goal of writing the dynamical equations of motion of the brain (model brain function).

Comment: I agree, this is a biophysics question, and a very interesting one. But I don't think it is on topic for this site. The biophysics tag indicates the question needs to primarily be about physics.